# XCode 3.2.6 forcing iPad as Active Executable for simulator

Tags: xcode

Have exactly the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725493/closed-xcode-3-2-6-forcing-ipad-as-active-executable). But it's solution does not work for me! I connected both iPhone and iPad devices, but still after changing Device to Simulator or cleaning while Simulator is selected XCode selects iPad Simulator's Active Executable. Which is very strange since my project is iPhone only (Target Device Family = iPhone).

I've experienced same problem Xcode 3.2.6 version released on 10 March (the same day as XCode 4 was released). But then somehow problem gone (may be after I've connected a device?).

Few days ago when Xcode 4.0.1 was released, I've found that XCode 3.2.6 was updated too on ADC (image posted on 25 Mar). So I've downloaded it, compared image to "old" XCode 3.2.6 image from 10 Mar, found differences and installed it.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem? I'm having the exact same thing.

Comment: Just switched to XCode 4. In 4.1 many obvious bugs were fixed. So it's rather usable now.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug in Xcode 3.2.6 that's fixed in 4.x. If it's that annoying to you, it's probably worth switching to Xcode 4.

Besides, Xcode 4 is the future (like it or not) and Xcode 3 is not likely to get any more enhancements.